When queried the CartEntry Type using Flexible Search Query, the product column has a PK even after the deletion of the product entry
After adding 2 products to the cart from AcceleratorStorefront, I have deleted those products via the Backoffice. When I tried querying the CartEntry type via Flexible search query in hac, the product column for those cart entries still referring a PK.
I have tried the following snippet and it returned 0 entries. My expectation is 2 entries as I have deleted 2 products.
return flexibleSearchService.<CartEntryModel>search("select {PK} from {CartEntry} where {product} IS NULL").getResult().size();

But the same query returned expected result, when executed after accessing the cart entries from the backoffice or calling cartEntry.getProduct() via code. How do I get the expected result without doing so?

You are trying an expected behavior. Normally we never delete products from online catalog. Because we have order history, email messages, etc. We just mark them as not sellable (hidden). We have data retention framework for removing old data after long times (it depends on your company, many 3 year, maybe 6 months). During deleting this kind of data we are checking relations and sometimes we don't delete them.
Normally hybris has cascade logic to delete related items. We are using partOf modifiers for an attribute. But if you have a lot of data likes order entries it creates performance bottleneck. Also you don't want to delete related items because of you don't want to lost the history.
You are getting empty result because hybris has logic to check product still there and has valid data.

Got it! Thanks! So If I want to delete the product, there is no other way than accessing each element via model service and then calling cartEntry.getProduct() to remove the reference to pk

You also need to check other related items with product: carts, stocks, prices, variants, etc.
